# Sort files into directories named by prefix of file

Tags: files, sort

I have a bunch of files like this

```
5830_1.png
5830_2.png
5830_3.png
5831_1.png
5832_1.png
5832_2.png
```

I'd like to sort these files all into directories that take the prefix of the file name as the name of the directory.

So I'd end up with

```
5830/
    5830_1.png
    5831_2.png
    ...etc
5831/
5832/
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

POSIX `sh` one-liner:

```
for file in *.png; do mkdir -p -- "${file%%_*}" && \
    mv -- "$file" "${file%%_*}"; done
```

Explanation:

- Loop over every `.png` file in current directory.
- `mkdir` with the file prefix; `${file%%_*}` removes the first underscore and everything following it; the `-p` ensures `mkdir` will be quiet if directory already exists.
- `mv` the file into the directory.

---

Per HalosGhost's suggestion below, if the desired end structure is

```
5830/
    1.png
    2.png
    3.png
5831/
    1.png
5832/
    1.png
    2.png
```

the above one-liner can be modified slightly:

```
for file in *.png; do mkdir -p -- "${file%%_*}" && \
    mv -- "${file}" "${file%%_*}/${file##*_}"; done
```

This time, the destination is composed of the directory `${file%%_*}` (`$file` before the underscore) and the new file name `${file##*_}` (`$file` after the underscore).

Comment: Though the OP didn't specify, it looks like they may be expecting the files to be placed at, e.g., `5830/1.png`, not `5830/5830_1.png` (which, if I'm not mistaken, is where they will end). Perhaps it would be useful to offer that as another one-liner?

Comment: I tried this, and at first I didn't think it was working,  but it just took some time to go through all the thousands of files I had

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something like this to sort out a bunch of files a few times.  I have found that bash variable expansion is your friend.

```
   ${parameter%word}
   ${parameter%%word}
```

Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.

Initial setup:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 falsenames falsenames 0 Jun  5 17:35 5830_1.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 falsenames falsenames 0 Jun  5 17:35 5830_2.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 falsenames falsenames 0 Jun  5 17:35 5830_3.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 falsenames falsenames 0 Jun  5 17:35 5831_1.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 falsenames falsenames 0 Jun  5 17:35 5832_1.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 falsenames falsenames 0 Jun  5 17:35 5832_2.png


$ for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do mkdir -p ${i%_*};mv -v $i ${i%_*}; done
'./5830_3.png' -> './5830/5830_3.png'
'./5831_1.png' -> './5831/5831_1.png'
'./5830_1.png' -> './5830/5830_1.png'
'./5832_1.png' -> './5832/5832_1.png'
'./5832_2.png' -> './5832/5832_2.png'
'./5830_2.png' -> './5830/5830_2.png'
```

You can get more specific using '-name *png' or some other flags on find, too.  I ran that through a find with maxdepth set to only check the specified directory.  This way it can be run again without modification if more images are added to that directory.  I also used % instead of %% so that this will not break if you have to specify a full directory that includes an underscore, like "/home/user/my_files/pngs"

```
$ for i in $(find move_files -maxdepth 1 -type f); do mkdir -p ${i%_*};mv -v $i ${i%_*}; done
'move_files/5830_3.png' -> 'move_files/5830/5830_3.png'
'move_files/5831_1.png' -> 'move_files/5831/5831_1.png'
'move_files/5830_1.png' -> 'move_files/5830/5830_1.png'
'move_files/5832_1.png' -> 'move_files/5832/5832_1.png'
'move_files/5832_2.png' -> 'move_files/5832/5832_2.png'
'move_files/5830_2.png' -> 'move_files/5830/5830_2.png'
```