# BASH: Renaming and organizing files based on information in the filenames

Tags: bash, sed, files, rename, gawk

Suppose I have a bunch of files has information separated by underscores:

nickname_username_realname_date_filename.txt

I want to make a directory for each username and rename the file to get rid of nickname_username_date_ and move that file (which is now named name.txt) into it's username directory

```
for f in *txt
         sed -F_'{$nick $user $realname $date $filename} $f
         $(mkdir -p $user)
         $(rename 's/???/$filename/g' $fullFileName)
         $(mv $fullFileName $user)
```

Comment: So if I have a file like this: "chuck_charles_important_2019-11-27_unimportant.txt" (so the mapping is that "chuck" is the nickname, "charles" is the username, "important" is the realname, "2019-11-17" is the date and "unimportant" is the filename, it should be moved into the subdirectory "charles" of the current directory (which should be created if necessary) and named what exactly: "important.txt", "unimportant.txt" or something else? And do you really want to throw away the nickname and the date?

Comment: I want to make a directory for each username and when renaming I only want what is in $filename kinda like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134730/sort-files-into-directories-named-by-prefix-of-file but I am confused how to pick the field seperator you want from this answer because there is only one

Comment: Well, I'm confused about what is in $filename, so can you please answer my question for the specific example I provided?

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt if I understand you correctly:

```
for i in *.txt; do
  IFS='_' read -r -a array <<< "$i"
  mkdir -p "${array[1]}" && mv "$i" "${array[1]}"/"${array[4]}"
done
```

---

Create an array with `_` as separator

```
IFS='_' read -r -a array <<< "$i"
```

---

Create the directory with the username `"${array[1]}"` and move the filename `"${array[4]}"`to that directory.

```
mkdir -p "${array[1]}" && mv "$i" "${array[1]}"/"${array[4]}"
```

Use with caution